# the remote end hung up unexpectedly error on git

Tags: git, github

I use Windows 7. I set up git on windows. I set my user information. I used git for a few project before. It was working before. For a while, I did not use github. Yesteday, I tried to clone a project of my friend form git using git shell for windows. I took

```
the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

error. Screenshot is below:

[image]

I do not know what the problem is. What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is the remote server, github? Does this occur repeatedly?

Comment: Please post the output of `git config -l`

Comment: What git client did you install on Windows, and what is the remote server?